# find the amount of elements in a char array

Tags: arrays, char, size

so im trying to write a program to convert binary to decimal and i have everything correct exect i dont get the correct answer because i dont know how to get the amount of elements that are inputed into the array this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a=0;

 int main ()
 {
  char  bin[20];
  int i=0, len, r=0, w;

  printf("Enter a Binary Number:  ");
  scanf("%s",bin);
  printf("\n");

 len = sizeof(bin); /*i know this is my problem how do i get len to be the size 
of the input of the user for example if the user puts 1010 len should be 4*/

  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
     {
          r = r * 2 + (bin[i] == '1' ? 1 : 0);
       }

   printf("Decimal is: %d\n\n",r);

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: arrays and pointers do not know how long they are. This is why C style strings have a 0 at the end to help distinguish it from arbitrary array of bytes... you need to store the length elsewhere, or use an abstract data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the strlen function in header string.

i.e.

```
#include<string>
```

Instead of sizeof(bin), use the strlen function

```
len = strlen(bin);
```

Comment: thank you so much i had tried the strlen but apparently included the wrong library (conio) i think it was thank you so much